# How to achieve bean Inheritance in apache aries blueprint

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi, spring-dm, aries

Currently we are migrating our application from Spring-DM to Aries Blueprint. Need a way to use the bean inheritance. I read that the parent attribute is not supported in blueprint.

Comment: Are you just setting parameter values or other? If so, using config admin property placeholders would allow for the value to be set in one place and then used in several.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this is not possible.  Inheritance is not supported by the Blueprint specification.  This is based on reading of the specification and discussing this problem with veterans with many years under their belt with JBoss Fuse, OSGi and Blueprint.  It is not clear to me why this important feature was not brought forward from Spring.